# Active MQ clustering using http auto discovery with multi cast on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, activemq-classic, multicast, autodiscovery

We are trying to set up the active MQ cluster on production environment on Amazon EC2 with Auto discover and multicast. 
I was able to configure successfully auto discovery with multi-cast on my local active mq server but on Amazon EC2 it is not working.

From the [link](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Discovery-without-multicast-like-on-EC2-td3658967.html)
I found that Amazon EC2 does not support multi-cast. Hence we have to use HTTP transport or VPN for multi-cast. I tried HTTP transport for multi-cast by downloading activemq-optional-5.6.jar (we are using Active-MQ 5.6 version). It requires httpcore and httpClient jars to servlet in it class path.

In broker configuration(activemq.xml)

```
`
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector name="default" uri="http://localhost:8161/activemq/DiscoveryRegistryServlet"/>
    </networkConnectors>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="activemq" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" discoveryUri="http://localhost:8161/activemq/DiscoveryRegistryServlet"/>
    </transportConnectors>`
```

are added.

But broker is not identifying the DiscoveryRegistryServlet.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out how to setup active MQ auto discovery with HTTP

**Active-MQ Broker configuration:**

1. In $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/webapps folder create a new folder

```
|_activemq
      |_WEB-INF
             |_classes
             |_web.xml
```

create a web.xml file with the following contents

```
    <web-app>

        <display-name>ActiveMQ Message Broker Web Application</display-name>
        <description>
            Provides an embedded ActiveMQ Message Broker embedded inside a web application
        </description>

        <!-- context config -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
            <param-value>tcp://localhost:61617</param-value>
            <description>The URL that the embedded broker should listen on in addition to HTTP</description>
        </context-param>
        <!-- servlet mappings -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>DiscoveryRegistryServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.transport.discovery.http.DiscoveryRegistryServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DiscoveryRegistryServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

1. Place **httpclient-4.0.3.jar, httpcore-4.3.jar, xstream-1.4.5.jar and activemq-optional-5.6.0.jar** in  **$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib** directory.
2. In **$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/config** directory, modify the **jetty.xml** file to expose activemq web app.

```
    <bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        ...
        <property name="handler">
                <bean id="sec" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                    <property name="handlers">
                ...
                ...
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                                        <property name="contextPath" value="/activemq" />
                                        <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/activemq" />
                                        <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                                        <property name="parentLoaderPriority" value="true" />
                    ...
                    ...
                </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

1. Modify activemq.xml file in  $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/conf directory to use http protocol

```
    <broker name=”brokerName”>
    ...
     <networkConnectors>
          <networkConnector name="default" uri="http://<loadbalancer_IP>:<locadbalancer_Port>/activemq/DiscoveryRegistryServlet?group=test"/>
          <!--<networkConnector name="default-nc" uri="multicast://default"/>-->
           </networkConnectors>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="http" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61618" discoveryUri="http://<loadbalancer_IP>:<locadbalancer_Port>/activemq/test"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    ...
    </broker>
```

make sure that the broker names are unique. “test” in url is the group name of brokers.
Client configuration:
1. Keep  httpclient-4.0.3.jar, httpcore-4.3.jar, xstream-1.4.5.jar and activemq-optional-5.6.0.jar in classpath of client
2. URL to be use by client

```
    discovery:(http://<loadbalancer_IP>:<locadbalancer_Port>/activemq/test)connectionTimeout=10000
```

here “test” is the group name.

Comment: Comment from [Ranka Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191876/ranka-nair): The correct `networkConnectorURI` is the same as the transport URI (../activemq/test)

Comment: This solution is excellent, but I have one question, when I look into activeMQ admin, inside "Queues", I can see the messages are enqued, but they are not dequed. Do you  know why this happens ? Any solution ?